# Ошибка компилятора при stdexcept

Tags: c++, компиляция, try-catch

Необходимо объявить исключение при введении юзером отрицательного числа.
В коде подключен `#include <stdexcept>`, но компилятор выдаёт ошибку "идентификатор invalid_argument не определен". Не могу понять причину.

```
    #include "jar.h"
#include <stdexcept> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void JarType::unitToEmpty()
{
    numUnits = 0;
}
void JarType::add(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0) {
        numUnits += n;
    }


    else {
        throw invalid_argument("Invalid value to add");
    }
}

void JarType::subtract(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0) 
        numUnits -= n;
}
```

Comment: `std::invalid_argument`?

Comment: Если указывать std::invalid_argument, то при сборке вся программа останавливается на этом пункте и выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Какую именно ошибку?

Comment: Нашла в чём проблема. Нужно было добавить в код using namespace std. При сборке, когда пытаешься ввести отрицательное значение программа в данном точке выдаёт: Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x76ABB5B2 в H02.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::invalid_argument по адресу памяти 0x00FFF4B8."

Comment: Ошибка не при сборке, а во время работы программы. Все работает как надо - вы бросили исключение, и студия вам об этом сказала. *"Нужно было добавить в код using namespace std"* Оба варианта делают одно и то же. См. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2752075)

Comment: Cпасибо. А каким образом не просто останавливать программу, а вывести для юзера "Invalid value to add". В данный момент сообщения нет, просто констатация ошибки.

Comment: Использовать `try {...} catch (const std::exception& e) {...}`. [Вот тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) есть примеры.

Comment: Всё получилось. Большое вам спасибо за помощь !